# AngularJS drag and drop with automatic scrolling

Tags: angularjs, scroll, drag-and-drop

I have an array of filters. Each filter can be a single filter or an array of filters (not recursive, stops with the first level).

I want to display it in a ribbon and allow dragging a filter on top of another, making that filter be added to the array of the other filter.

Only 3 filters will be able to show at once and you can reach others by scrolling horizontally.

I want to be able to automatically scroll while dragging if reached the right/left edge.

There are plenty of ways to implement drag and drop but I'm afraid I'll be in a ditch when I try to add automatic scrolling to them.

How would you suggest going about this? Where do I start? Is there some library that giving me one of my two needs, the second will be easy to implement?

I've tried illustrating what I mean in a pic. Excuse my none existant PS skills and my poor mspaint skills. Dragging a filter X on filter Y will remove X and create an array in the place of Y consisting of X and Y.

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

This may be helpful It is working in my case.If you have better solution please share.
I have used ngDraggable for drag and drop and on ng-drag-move event call following function like ng-drag-move="dragContainer($event)"

```
  $scope.dragContainer=function(ev){
              var scrollPostion=$('#sasha').scrollLeft();
              console.log(scrollPostion);
              if(ev.tx>0)
              {
                $('#sasha').scrollLeft(scrollPostion+1);
              }
              else
              {
                  $('#sasha').scrollLeft(scrollPostion-1);  
              }

              console.log('dragging');
            }
```

where sasha is div Id on which you want to add scroll bar

Comment: This will work. There is small caveat in this approach. There is no way to stop scrolling once you dropped the object. The scrolling continues for all the move event got fired. Atleast I could not found a solution for that.